# How do you apply pending explicit migrations in visual studios community edition? (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to modify my code first migration so that I can add a new table to the db, called "GunControl." However, when I enter "Add-Migration GunControl" in the package manager, I get the error message:

"Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201705171404346_Questionnaire]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration."

QuestionnaireDbEntities.mdf is the name of by db, and GunControl inherits from the class Questionnaire. I have looked everywhere online, and I can't find a way to do this. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because you have an existing database already that you're connecting to. The database keeps track of what migrations have been applied to it and when you run `Add-Migration` it compares the database schema with your models and sees that you've created a migration previously (`201705171404346_Questionnaire`) which has not yet been applied to the actual database. Because of this, the new migration can't determine what has changed in the schema when comparing the database.

Your options are:

1. Run `Update-Database` to apply the previous migration.
2. Delete the migration file `201705171404346_Questionnaire.cs` and then run `Add-Migration` again which will contain both sets of changes.
3. Delete the entire database and all migration files, then run `Add-Migration` to create the initial schema.